# Use command argument in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, arguments

When I define a new command to draw an axis I want to use one argument to calculate the step size of the tick  numbers. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
\newcommand{\axistest}[2]{
  \draw[->,color=black] (0,0) -- (#1+0.5,0);
  \foreach \x in {1, ..., #1} {
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $#2*\x$};
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \axistest{5}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following as output:

[image: latex output]

But I want the numbers to be 2, 4, 6, etc.

I get the same output when I remove the dollar signs around `#2*\x`.

Comment: Can you please provide minimal code, we can copy, paste amd run? E.g. besides the preamble there should at least be a call to your newcommand. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask Ti*k*Z to write text into your nodes, it writes text. If you want to compute a value to be printed into the node, you have to evaluate the label into the `foreach` definition (for example):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630831/204164

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,color=black] (0,0) -- (5+0.5,0);
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \l using int(2*\x)] in {1, ..., 5} {
            \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\l$};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: foreach and computation]

Since you didn't provide an MWE, I didn't insert the commands into a `newcommand`, but I'm sure you could figure it out by yourself.

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for! Works as expected, thank you!